# How to stop recrawling and reindexing the pages on my website?

Tags: wordpress, indexing, seo, google-crawlers

I have about 2 million pages on my website (Wordpress) . The google is always crawl many pages on my website (recrawl old pages) and recently it took about 3 days to index the new pages in order to show in google result.

How to stop recrawl?

Sample of my sitemap : http://www.serze.com/post_part1.xml

Comment: You will not be able to keep google from revisiting sites that it has indexed - google wants to know if anything changed. You can indicate to google that you want certain parts not crawled, either via [robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) or [robots meta tag](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag?hl=en).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discourage search engine from indexing  choice is your entire site will make non accessible for google. Your website wont rank on search result after that.

You can set update frequency for specific pages on your sitemap.xml.

https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html (check changefreq  and  priority tag)

Also you can check crawl stats on search console.
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620?hl=en

But it might be different problem. Did you anything for seo or software updates?

Answer (score 1):

[image]For that just go to **admin** > **settings** > **Reading** enable Discourage search engine from indexing this site.

and for Google create a separate robot.txt